# How to vectorize the following python code?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to use Numpy and vectorization operations to make a section of code run faster but I don't succeed to find a solution. If somebody has an idea... Thanks.

Here's the working code with loops:

```
y = np.zeros(len(tab))
for i in range(len(tab)):
    s =  0
    for n in range(len(coef[0])):
        s += coef[0][n] * ((a + b * np.dot(tab[i], vectors[n])) ** d)
    y[i] = s
```

Where,

- tab: numpy.array(N,M)
- vectors: numpy.array(P,M)
- coef: numpy.array(1,P)
- a, b, c: constants (a = 0, if it's more easy)

Comment: Can you include a sentence at the beginning of your question describing what the code is supposed to accomplish? It's hard to give a pure programmatic assessment.

Comment: @mprat - it's a part of SVM algorithm implementation, similar to this implementation [link](https://gist.github.com/mblondel/586753) - lines 83-88

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an approach based on [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) and [`matrix-multiplication with np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) as listed  below -

```
# Calculate "((a + b * np.dot(tab[i], vectors[n])) ** d)" part
p1 = (a + b*np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors))**d

# Include "+= coef[0][n] *" part to get the final output
y_vectorized = np.dot(coef,p1)
```

---

**Runtime test**

Dataset #1:

This is a quick runtime test comparing the original loopy approach with the proposed approach for some random values -

```
In [168]: N = 50
     ...: M = 50
     ...: P = 50
     ...: 
     ...: tab = np.random.rand(N,M)
     ...: vectors = np.random.rand(P,M)
     ...: coef = np.random.rand(1,P)
     ...: 
     ...: a = 3.233
     ...: b = 0.4343
     ...: c = 2.0483
     ...: d = 3
     ...: 

In [169]: %timeit original_approach(tab,vectors,coef,a,b,c,d)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.18 ms per loop

In [170]: %timeit proposed_approach(tab,vectors,coef,a,b,c,d)
10000 loops, best of 3: 136 µs per loop
```

Dataset #2:

With `N`, `M` and `P` as `150` each, the runtimes were -

```
In [196]: %timeit original_approach(tab,vectors,coef,a,b,c,d)
10 loops, best of 3: 37.9 ms per loop

In [197]: %timeit proposed_approach(tab,vectors,coef,a,b,c,d)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks terrible. But is it what you need?

```
y = array([ sum( [coef[0][n] * ((a + b * np.dot(tab[i], vectors[n])) ** d) 
            for n in range(len(vectors[0]))] ) for i in range(len(tab)) ])
```

Comment: With the same dataset, my implementation: total runtime = 28min and for your implementation: total runtime = 15min. It's better, but isn't there a better solution, without using these 2 loops?

Comment: this isn't vectorizing, you still have 2 `for` loops even though you use `numpy` to speed it up a bit..

Comment: This just rewrites the 2 loop as list comprehensions.  Still a Python loop, just a bit more efficient.